# How to free up a key combination in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys

I want to assign a hotkey to a function, but the keys are already used in some other functions' combination.
How can I easely remove this hotkey from all these entries so I free it up and am able to asign it to the function I want?

Comment: is anybody actually using the default hotkeys? Those aren't hotkeys, those are hot..sentences or something.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Visual Studio C# Express 2008, but you can go into **Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard**. If you put your cursor in the **Press shortcut keys** field and type the key you want to remap, it will show you what commands use that key and let you clear or change the assignments.

Comment: I know about showing where it is mapped to, but how do I clear them except for navigating to each one of them and removing them one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Go assign the command a shortcut (Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard). If it's already taken, that will display, but it won't keep you from assigning it to something else (which removes the shortcut from the original task).

Comment: well, as long as I don't remove the hotkey from the other functions, it isn't working ...

Answer (score 0):

Some key shortcuts are layered.  So for instance while editing text the Text Editor keys override the Global ones.  If you set your shortcut for the priority layer you can ignore whatever is assigned on a lower layer.  So for text editing keys assign them under Text Editing and not Global to avoid them being ignored.

Repeat this for as many layers that you run into.  I do this part incrementally only if there is some other context I want that same shortcut for.